# Inserting YahooFinance data into SQL database using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, yahoo-finance, pypyodbc

I am trying to insert data retrieved from YahooFinance into a SQL Server database, using Python's pypyodbc.

I am using the code below:

```
import pypyodbc
import ystockquote

conn = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=serv;DATABASE=TEST;UID=uid;PWD=pwd')

cur = conn.cursor()

var1 = ystockquote.get_historical_prices('GOOG','201403027','20140411')
data = var1[1:]

columnBased = [[data[i][j] for i in range(len(data))] for j in range(len(data[0]))]

cur.execute("INSERT INTO [TEST].[dbo].[StockData] (Date, OpenPrice, ClosePrice, High, Low, Volume, Adj_Close) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?", (data))

cur.commit()
cur.close()
```

This yields the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 32, in <module>
cur.execute("INSERT INTO [TEST].[dbo].[StockData] (Date, OpenPrice, ClosePrice, High, Low, Volume, Adj_Close) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?", (data))
  File "file.py", line 1458, in execute
self._BindParams(param_types)
  File "file.py", line 1263, in _BindParams
if param_types[col_num][0] == 'u':
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What might I be doing wrong? Note that I am a Python novice and have previously done such retrievals and database insertion using MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for havig wasted your time, the answer is ctually quite simple. I needed to amend the above code using:

```
for item in data:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO [TEST].[dbo].[StockData] (Date, OpenPrice, ClosePrice, High, Low, Volume, Adj_Close) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", item)
```